# Is there a poset which has an element which does not have immediate succesor and is not maximal as well?

Tags: order-theory

Here's my question: If $A$ is a partially ordered set and suppose some element $a$ of $A$ does not have any immediate successor then is $a$ maximal in $A$? The converse is obviously true because if $a$ were maximal then $a$ cannot have a immediate successor because that would contradict the definition. Now, if $A$ was well ordered and if I assume that $a$ was not maximal then the set $\{ x\in A : a<x \}$ would be nonempty and so the least element of this set would be the immediate successor. What about in the case where $A$ is not so special? I tried to think about it but could not come up with proof or a counterexample.

Comment: How about $\Bbb Q$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A = (-1,1] \cup (2,3)$ in the order inherited from $\Bbb R$ (so a linear order) has element $1$ that is not maximal (e.g. $2\frac12 \in A$ is larger) but has no immediate successor.

Also in $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb Q$ *all* elements are not maximal and none of them have immediate successors.

Comment: It's a shame that I was not able to get that.

Comment: @AshishK sometimes you just have to think of the obvious examples.

Answer (score 2):

Order natural numbers so that 1 is less than any other number, and the rest is reversed:

> 1 < ...... < 7 < 6 < 5 < 4 < 3 < 2.

Number 1 in this ordering satisfies your requrements - it's not maximal but it has no immediate successor.